# Non-Significant T-tests but significant F-Test, even though my VIF is generally low

Tags: r, regression, anova, multiple-regression, t-test

For my linear regression, I have response variable and two predictors. My second predictor is an interaction between the first predictor and a factor because I wanted to see how the predictor changes for different levels of the factor. I am seeing non-significant p-values for t-test, however when I run an ANOVA I get a significant p-value for the F-test. I checked VIF for colinearity, however my VIF seems low for the variable. Could someone help me interpret this and what I should try for next steps? Should I keep it?

**VIF:**

```
                            GVIF Df    GVIF(1/(2Df))
```

name                       10.410272 96        1.012277

r_score              7.024539  1        2.650385

r_score:s_rating 40.295458 10        1.202992

**ANOVA**

Analysis of Variance Table

Response: raw
                             Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value    Pr(>F)
name                         96  70758  737.06 23.3344 < 2.2e-16 ***
r_score                1    476  476.24 15.0770 0.0001067 ***
r_score:s_rating   10    636   63.64  2.0147 0.0284765 *
Residuals                  1908  60268   31.59

**Part of summary output:**

r_score                                       2.087e-02  9.723e-03   2.147 0.031940 *
r_score:s_rating2                         -1.760e-02  1.047e-02  -1.680 0.093104 .
r_score:s_rating3                         -6.385e-03  1.026e-02  -0.622 0.533968
r_score:s_rating4                         -1.719e-02  9.885e-03  -1.739 0.082208 .
r_score:s_rating5                         -2.466e-03  9.886e-03  -0.249 0.803017
r_score:s_rating6                         -8.633e-04  1.040e-02  -0.083 0.933881
r_score:s_rating7                          1.531e-03  1.087e-02   0.141 0.888075
r_score:s_rating8                          9.868e-03  1.153e-02   0.856 0.392024
r_score:s_rating9                          7.046e-03  1.204e-02   0.585 0.558563
r_score:s_rating10                         5.876e-04  1.313e-02   0.045 0.964314
r_score:s_rating11                         9.853e-03  1.096e-02   0.899 0.368945

Comment: The t-tests and the F-tests don't test the same hypotheses ... I suggest you write down the tested hypothesis for each p-value. That should illuminate this.

Comment: So essentially would it be that these values are not significantly different from 0, however they do improve my model? Thanks for the input!

Comment: Do you know what treatment contrasts are?